# Sending integer V.S. ASCII through UART

Tags: ascii, uart

I am doing a project which requires me to send characters and numbers through UART.
The way I did was sending ASCII code through UART. For example, if I need to send character 'a', I will send 0x61. And if I need to send number 5, I will send 0x35. If I need to send 15, I first split it by character '1','5' and then send 0x31, 0x35 separately. 
Is there any other way to send integers, such as 15? Can I send an integer type of data? For example, can I send 0xff for integer 15 instead of sending ASCII code for '1' and '5'?

Comment: You can go ahead and send whatever 8 bit quantities will be understood by both sides. But in practice stuff sent over a serial line is restricted to 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: @Mark Ransom is right about using "whatever 8 bit quantities will be understood by both sides", but as it appears you are starting out, stick with 7-bit ASCII.